# I wait, What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I can help retrieve
> But I cause great loss
> I wait, but not too long
> Communication is key

**What word am I?**

Hint:

> Patterns

Hint 2:

> Attached to other words

Comment: A hint [does not fix your puzzle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5008/69582). Hints should be entirely supplementary and only the non-hidden parts are used to judge fairness and topicality

Comment: Not trying to fix my puzzle.. either way should I just delete this riddle?

Comment: Please see [If a puzzle appears to be too broad, should one change it if answers are already posted?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6256/if-a-puzzle-appears-to-be-too-broad-should-one-change-it-if-answers-are-already) and [Re-asking a question when an unintended answer is given](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/re-asking-a-question-when-an-unintended-answer-is-given) from [meta]

Answer (score 3):

Is it the

> Black Box of the airplanes (or other transportation)?

I can help retrieve

> Retrives all important data after an accident

But I cause great loss

> Result of a major accident. Although Black Box itself does not cause it

I wait, but not too long

> Black Box retrieval has time limit. It becomes non functional after a few months.

Communication is key

> Data in the box is the communication for the cause of the accident.

Comment: Great answer, but not exactly what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> TNT / explosives?

I can help retrieve

> You can get access to things that are blocked (like a collapsed cave).

But I cause great loss

> You can do a lot of damage with it

I wait, but not too long

> It has a fuse, once lit it will wait some time before exploding

Communication is key

> You have to make sure nobody is nearby when setting it of

hint

> You have to place it in a certain pattern to have a controlled explosion. (Does not fit as nice as the other anwsers)

Comment: You made this fit so well! I'm impressed, and also regretting not adding more lines to the riddle.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Morse Code

*I can help retrieve*

> Morse code is used to communicate, the standard Morse S.O.S. can help retrieve people in dangerous situations.

*But I cause great loss*

> Morse code, if not understood by someone, can just be ignored and cause a disaster for the author of the message.

*I wait, but not too long*

> Between letters, or even words, one must wait to properly understand, or transmit information (some professionals barely need to do so though)

*Communication is key*

> Morse code is used for communication, and the devices used to transmit morse are called [keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraph_key)

Comment: Closer to my intended answer, props for making it fit with the hint too.